# How to suppress JuMP from printing e.g., "Set parameter Method to value 2"?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I notice in the newer version of JuMP, after setting parameter info of solvers, this information is printed in the terminal. How can I suppress it?

```
Set parameter Method to value 2
Set parameter Crossover to value 1
Set parameter Method to value 1
Set parameter Crossover to value 0
Set parameter Method to value 1
Set parameter Method to value 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not coming from JuMP. It is a known bug in some versions of Gurobi, which prints even when `set_silent` is used

It might be fixed in the latest Gurobi release, but I haven't tried.